# jQuery .load() within .load()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

i have 3 partial views

**View 1:**

```
//_yard.cshtml
@model Yard
<div>@Model.Name</div>
<div class="yard"></div>

@foreach(var house in Model.Houses)
{
  <script  type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function{
   $(".yard").load("/community/Houses");
  });
  </script>
}
```

**View 2**

```
//_houses.cshtml
@model House
<div>@Model.Name<div>
<div class="house"></div>
@foreach(var level in Model.levels)
{
  <script  type="text/JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function{
    $(".house").load("/Community/Levels");
  });
  </script>
}
```

**View 3:**

```
//_levels.cshtml
@model Level
<div>@Model.Name<div>
<div class="room"></div>
@foreach(var room in Model.Rooms)
{
  <script  type="text/JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function{
    $(".room").load("/Community/Rooms");
  });
  </script>
}
```

The above sample, shows that i am loading a `View 1` within another view using `jQuery Load()`, i then load `View 2` withing `View 1`, and then and so forth, however, the first load() works fine, but the subsequint loads does not fire.

I think it is due to the `$(document).ready();` function not being reset, however, i am not sure how to reset it on each load.

**Problem Solved**
With MVC the default template renders the jQuery script at the bottom of the page. I moved it to the top, and the ajax loads worked.

I know this makes no sense, but it fixed the problem. I will update the question after doing a little bit more investigation as to why this solves the problem.

Comment: On a side note, purely based on the samples you provided above, I think it would make more sense not to use JavaScript at all. When you perform your @foreach, I would put a Html.RenderPartial() there instead of JavaScript and generate the entire HTML on the server side, instead of loading part of the page on the server, and loading the rest with multiple AJAX calls from the client.

Comment: i have to load it using ajax, the subsequent partials take long to load as the data is pulled from various web services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
*The answer below in general is helpful, but I think the real problem is syntax errors in your JavaScript. The `.load()` lines of code all have one too many `)` at the end. Fix that, make sure you do not have more syntax errors by checking the JavaScript console in your browser, then also use the advice below :-)*

Thinking about `$(document).ready();` being "reset" is unhelpful, because it isn't and cannot be "reset".

It is an event that is fired the first time the DOM has been fully loaded and ready to be manipulated by JavaScript. The event happens once, and only once, when a web page is loaded for the first time. Any subsequent AJAX requests will not fire new `$(document).ready();` events on the page. They will, however, fire other events - but not `$(document).ready();`.

Remove `$(document).ready();` from View 2 and 3 and your code will work. (Tip: you should wrap your JavaScript in `<script>` tags, otherwise you may get some weird behaviour in some browsers).

The events that fire when AJAX requests have finished may help you out:

- `$.ajax();` has a `success`/`error`/`complete` handlers.
- `.load();` has a `complete` handler.

Comment: simply removing the `$(document).ready();` does not cause the next load to execute. The `<script>` tags is now in my example. (they were always present in my code)

Comment: Forget about View 3 for now. Does this work in View 2: <script  type="text/javascript"> alert("View 2 JavaScript is being executed"); </script>

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors too. The end <script> tag should be </script> and you have one too many ) at the end of each .load() line. Use a tool like JSLint or a JavaScript console in your browser to make sure the JavaScript valid.

Comment: i'll fix the syntex errors on the examples quickly,the examples are purely examples, to explain what i am trying to achieve

Comment: I found a solution, and updated the question with my findings. Just to let you know, removing the `$(document).ready();` section breaks my "Now Working" solution